# Get the console log of website and send to websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, puppeteer

I have the following situation:

I want to get the console log of a website and send that to WebSocket clients.

I was able to create a node server and send data to connected users with below code.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 2222 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.send("sending the sample data");
});
```

I was able to get the console log of website using following code:

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--window-size=1920x1080'
    ]
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://example.com/test.php');

  page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));

})();
```

Here `page.on` is a callback function, which is called every time there is a console log. How do I broadcast that msg (console.log from puppeteer) to WebSocket clients?

Please note that the website is opened once only when the app is started and console.log output is generated using setInterval every second. So new users get only the latest data.

Comment: Basically you need to open a connection to the server. But if the websocket server is the same node instance you are using to open puppeteer you don't need to use a websocket at all.... Anyway, to send messages to ws clients you just need `ws.send('something');`

Comment: No its not same server, I am broadcasting to all clients

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `console.log(msg.text())` you need to broadcast the message to all ws clients, right?

So a simple code will be:

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(msg.text());
    }
  });
});
```

[Read here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#server-broadcast) for more info

Comment: Hi , it is working in localhost , but not working in my cloud server !!

Comment: "not working" is not enough info to try to help you. If you have specific issue with your cloud server, you can ask a new question, or provide more info. If my answer solved your question, please accept it as the correct answer.